# Wordpress Insert Image or image path on database

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I don't want to use Wordpress' built in media uploader.

I have a form (on the frontend) of my site, and I need to allow anyone to upload an image to my uploads folder in wp-content. I've found many tutorials, but they all tell me how to do it with the wordpress uploader. I need to be able to validate what users are uploading.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to use the Wordpress media upload function to upload your files.

You can use your own scripts with Wordpress using the enqueue_script function.

[Create a template file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) and code your own uploader.

I personally use [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) but I guess you can use any of the scripts available.